# Calling recursive function by struct

Tags: c++, recursion, struct

First of all take a look at my struct

```
 typedef struct  {
   int treeDepth;
   unsigned __int8 dmv[19];
   unsigned __int8 dv[19];
   unsigned __int8 ih;
   bool flagLeft = true ;
   bool flagRight = true;
}problem_t;
```

I have a function which works with this struct,

```
void PMSprune(problem_t &problem)
 {
  /*
   --blocks of code!
   --modify properties of "problem"
  */
  PMSprune(problem);// I want to call it with problem.treeDepth++, but I 
  //don't want my original struct to be modified
 }
```

But this function is recursive, and I want to call this function with one of the properties of the struct being modified, does anyone have any idea how can I do this?

**UPDATE:**
my project is real time, the time is really important for me, and this function is being called inside a loop about a million times

Comment: Either take a copy of the stuct in each recursive call and modify it. Or move treeDepth out of the struct.

Comment: as i mentioned above, I have time matter, if take copy of struct, loading every properties of the struct again would take much time for me

Comment: The assignment in your struct definition is not possible in C/C++.

Comment: @Wolf It's not C, it's C++. They aren't the same thing. And it is possible in C++11 and up.

Comment: @user975989 Wow! [This](https://ideone.com/wcLeHA) is really great news! Thanks for correcting me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the function:

```
void PMSpruneRec(problem_t &problem, int treeDepth)
 {
  /*
   --blocks of code!
   --modify properties of "problem"
  */
  PMSpruneRec(problem, treeDepth + 1);
 }
void PMSprune(problem_t &problem)
 {
  PMSpruneRec(problem, problem.treeDepth);
 }
```

Of course, you'll still need some termination condition.

Comment: Thank you, It's not a bad idea, but i have tons of code that treedepth is inside problem_t, another thing is, I don't think it's such a good idea to define treedepth again

Comment: In that case, you need to clarify what it is you actually want.

Answer (score 0):

Just copy it before the change:

```
void PMSprune(problem_t &problem)
{
  /*
   --blocks of code!
  */
  problem_t new_problem = problem
  /*
   --modify properties of "new_problem"
  */
  PMSprune(new_problem);
}
```

Comment: This will mean that the modifications inside the recursive calls will not affect the original struct.

Comment: @SebastianRedl Right, as he asked "I don't want my original struct to be modified"

Comment: I presume he meant "I don't want treeDepth modified, but other field modifications should apply", because otherwise why would he take the struct by non-const reference in the first place, and have "modify properties of "problem"" in the comment?

Comment: @SebastianRedl Well, I can't read his mind but I thought that the "modify properties of "problem"" also should not effect the original struct. And he can change it to const indeed.

Comment: If I make another instance, that would take much time for me to load every member again

Comment: @ShaheenZahedi you should explain what can or needed to be modified in the original struct and what doesn't. Also what can be changed and what is forced by design.

Answer (score 0):

If a `treeDepth` by some design should be a `problem_t` member, you could simply reset its value after each recursive call:

```
void PMSprune(problem_t &problem)
 {
  /*
   --blocks of code!
   --modify properties of "problem"
  */
  ++problem.treeDepth;
  PMSprune(problem);// I want to call it with problem.treeDepth++, but I 
  //don't want my original struct to be modified
  --problem.treeDepth;
 }
```

Otherwise Sebastian's approach is better. It is more clear and structured.

Comment: Oo, Please give attention, I don't know how many times PMSprune would be called,  and also I don't know how many times treedepth will be incremented

Comment: Since it will be incremented and decremented after each recursive call, it should not matter how many times `PMSprune` will be called.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered turning it into a loop? It could even help performance-wise, since it's a nested call inside a tight loop.

```
void PMSprune(problem_t &problem)
{
    for(int treeDepth = problem.treeDepth; someStoppingCondition; ++treeDepth)
    {
        /*
        --blocks of code!
        --modify properties of "problem"
        */
    }
}
```

Obviously depends on what code you have there, just wanted to remind you of this possibility.